# Python - Передача self явно

Tags: python, ооп, классы

Решаю учебную задачу по ООП в Python:
Напишите код, эквивалентный последней строчке, но с явным указанием аргумента self метода f():

```
class C:
    def f(self):
        return self
o = C()
o.f()
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, что от меня хотят? Ведь параметр `self` передается автоматически без моего участия и попытка передать параметр в f приводит к ошибке `f() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Comment: `C.f(o)` . . . .

Comment: Если хочется острых ощущений, можно ещё так `o.f.__func__(o)`

Comment: Cattail Лучше приведите задачу.

Comment: @Александр а это вся задача, учебная она.

Comment: Но ведь это враньё "но с явным указанием аргумента self"

Comment: @andreymal спасибо, это работает.

Comment: @Александр почему враньё?

Comment: Потому что self передаётся не явно. а здесь def f(self): это просто аннотация.

Comment: @Александр посмотрите мои первые два комментария, в них self передаётся явно, это не враньё

Comment: А блин наоборот) прошу прощения.

Comment: Вообще у вас там не self явно передаётся. между С и o нет не чего общего.

Comment: C.f(o) это просто classmethod.

Comment: @Александр в случаях `o.f()` и `C.f(o)` значение `self` будет полностью одинаковым